# Add list of objects in JsonObject in java

Tags: java, json, list, object

I have the list of objects as below

```
List<sampleClass> data = .....;
```

How do I add this list as value to "sample" in the below code?

```
JsonObject a = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                       .add("abz", "xyz")
                       .add("sample", data)
                       .build();
```

If data has

```
        { 
          "a" : 2,
          "b" : 3
        }
```

I want the output to be

```
{
    "abz": "xyz",
    "sample": [{
        "a": 2,
        "b": 3
    }]
}
```

Comment: Create the array with `Json.createArrayBuilder()` then add it to the main `a` object before `.build();`

Answer (score 0):

Write Something like this.. (I didn't test the code)

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.accumulate("abz", "xyz").append("sample", data);
    System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Comment: The question is about javax.json.JsonObject, which is not the same thing as JSONObject.   The first comment on the question is the correct answer.